# How to write fraction value using html?

Tags: html, numbers, fractions

I want to write fraction value such as the picture below:

[image]

How do I write fraction value using html without using image?

NOTE: I don't want this 1 1/2 pattern but strictly just as the pic above

Comment: Times have changed and we can now use MathML. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525977/how-to-write-fraction-value-using-html/10081414#10081414).

Comment: @0b10011 To be fair: there is a [problem with browser support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525977/how-to-write-fraction-value-using-html#comment64486744_10081414) for your solution. It is still [like this in 2020](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml).

Comment: This source is pretty old, but I find it useful for creating simple fractions in HTML and CSS. https://www.periodni.com/mathematical_and_chemical_equations_on_web.html

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try the following:

```html
1<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>
```

This displays as:

1<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

Comment: In the most recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, inputting `1 1&frasl;2` will automatically convert the numerator and denominator to unicode super- and subscripts, which looks even better than HTML super- and subscripts: 1 1⁄2

Answer (score 45):

```css
.frac {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    letter-spacing: 0.001em;
    text-align: center;
}
.frac > span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.1em;
}
.frac span.bottom {
    border-top: thin solid black;
}
.frac span.symbol {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
1 <div class="frac">
    <span>1</span>
    <span class="symbol">/</span>
    <span class="bottom">2</span>
    
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is definitely visually the most pretty! Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly! I think this should be the accepted answer as in the question the asker wanted something looking EXACTLY the same, which is not what is in the accepted answer.

Comment: I also like how you have a backup way of displaying the fraction in case the CSS is disabled

Comment: Runs perfect. Thanks!

Comment: omg, this is such an underrated solution. The way it works it genius! Brilliant. +1

Answer (score 13):

The following code will be rendered just as the example in the question, and if the client does not support CSS it will be rendered as plain text, still readable as a fraction:

```html
<p>1 <span class="frac"><sup>12</sup><span>/</span><sub>256</sub></span>.</p>
```

```css
span.frac {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
span.frac > sup {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  font: inherit;
}
span.frac > span {
  display: none;
}
span.frac > sub {
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
}
```

The middle `<span>` serves only for the clients who do not render CSS - the text is still readable as `1 12/256` - and that's why you should place a space between the integer and the fraction.

You may want to change the font-size, because the resulting element may be a little taller than the other characters in the line, or you may want to use a relative position to shift it a little to the bottom.

But the general idea, as presented here, may be enough for the basic use.

Comment: When writing two fractions with a plus sign, the plus sign is not aligned. You can change this by wrapping the + sign with: `<span style="vertical-align:10px;">+</span>`, see result http://jsfiddle.net/hx5oyotq/1/

Answer (score 10):

Check out the following:

```css
span.frac {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span.frac > sup, span.frac > sub {
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}
span.frac > sup {border-bottom: 0.08em solid;}
span.frac > span {display: none;}
```

```html
<p>7&nbsp;<span class="frac"><sup>42</sup><span>&frasl;</span><sub>73</sub></span>.</p>
```

**[CodePen](https://codepen.io/giogziro95/pen/oBzQEd)**

Comment: omg, this is such an underrated solution. The way it works it genius! Brilliant. +1

Answer (score 7):

You can use `<sup>` and `<sub>` elements in conjunction with the *fraction slash entity* `&frasl;`

`<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>`  is <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

**UPDATE**: I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWC6y/) that shows a hyphenated fraction in HTML using a table.

```
   <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">1</td>
          <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px">1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>            
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Is that possible to use fraction hyphen instead of fraction slash?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be on the [1.4 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), so I guess there's no standard entity. I'm no css expert, so I'd do it with a two row, one column `<table>` with a border in the middle. Quick and dirty.  Here you can see it in action: [Math in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/#twodim)

Comment: The table is not a legal element in a `<p>`, so it will not be possible to use this solution in a sentence, for example. Besides that, the `<table>` should not be used for things other than tabular data.

Comment: Agree, your proposal is much better.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is an easier way for doing this. Use the following HTML.

```html
1 &frac12;
```

Result is 1 ½

Comment: Perfect! Simplest is best - all of these other answers are too much for something so simple.

Comment: what if I have a fraction such as 2/15, how can I write it ??

Comment: This actually renders a unicode character, there are just the most used fractions available, won't work with any fraction.
⅐ ⅑ ⅒ ⅓ ⅔ ⅕ ⅖ ⅗ ⅘ ⅙ ⅚ ⅛ ⅜ ⅝ ⅞ ¼ 
½ ¾

Answer (score 2):

Using `MathML` ([Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML)):

```html
<math>
 <mrow>
  <mn>1</mn>
  <mfrac>
   <mi>1</mi>
   <mi>2</mi>
  </mfrac>
 </mrow>
</math>
```

Comment: @Kartheeks As mentioned by jedierikb, MathML isn't fully supported by all browsers. It looks great in my default mobile browser though (Firefox), so it all depends on which browsers you're supporting.

Comment: More specifically, it doesn't work on *most* browsers.  That link shows only Safari 9.1+, iOS Safari 9.2+, and Firefox 46+ with MS Edge "Not currently planned" and Chrome "No longer pursuing".

Comment: Ah, the eternal chromium feature request: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152430

Comment: for cross browser support of MathMl use MathJax :-  <script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML">
</script>

Answer (score 2):

Using pure html and with margin property of br you can work around

```css
br {   
    content: "";
    margin: -1%;
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<big>1</big><sup> <u><big>1</big></u></sup><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<sup> <big>2</big></sup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using newer CSS methods. This method also uses custom tags, but you can change these to `<div class = "..."></div>` if you're not fond of custom tags.

**Copy the following to your CSS:**

*Use `.fraction` and `.numer` if you use classes instead*

```
fraction {
  display: inline-grid;

  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;

  font-size: 0.8em; // You can change fraction size here. I recommend 0.5em ~ 0.8em
  vertical-align: top;
}

numer {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

**You can now use the tags like this:**

```
Add 1 <fraction> <numer>1</numer> 2 </fraction> cups of flour into the bowl and stir.
```

Output

[image: Output Image]

I'd also recommend using read-only formatting for screen-reader output:

**CSS**

```
read {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
1 <fraction> <read>and</read> <numer>1</numer> <read>over</read> 2 </fraction>
```

Screen-reader: *"one and one over two..."*

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple "inline" HTML

```
a
<span style="display:inline-flex;flex-direction:column;vertical-align:middle;">
    <span>1</span>
    <span style="border-top:1px solid">2</span>
</span>
b
```

#### CodePen

https://codepen.io/eyedean/pen/bGMqBaB

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
br {   
    content: "";
    margin: -1%;
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<big>1</big><sup> <u><big>1</big></u></sup><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<sup> <big>2</big></sup>
```