# Fractions by HTML code in Mobile browser using phone gap

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

I tried all the code for showing a/b like
**a**
**_**
**b**
but its not working on the mobile browser. Its showing properly on the desktop browser.

Is there any way to solve this in mobile browser.

Code I tried is attached below
[image: here is the image]

Comment: check browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=math)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525977/how-to-write-fraction-value-using-html

Comment: Please explain what "its not working" means.

Comment: I have seen the same link and tried but in mobile its showing like `1/2` by using js and `1 2` by using <math>

Comment: What about the table option: http://jsfiddle.net/uWC6y/