# How to write rational number in html

Tags: html, number-formatting

Can any one tell me how to write this type of rational numbers in html browser? I tried so many ways but it doesn't works.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write fraction value using html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525977/how-to-write-fraction-value-using-html)

Comment: i mean i don't want "/" i want this "--" between numerator and denominator

Comment: Sorry the link was quite hard to follow. Here is a fiddle from the duplicate question http://jsfiddle.net/0L01p4m4/

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```html
s<sup>2</sup>&frasl;<sub>7</sub> &times; <sup>4</sup>&frasl;<sub>3</sub>?
```

If you prefer having a straight line instead of `/`, use this:

```css
.frac {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    letter-spacing: 0.001em;
    text-align: center;
    
    }
.frac > span { 
    display: block; 
    padding: 0.1em; 
    }
.frac span.bottom {border-top: thin solid black;}
.frac span.symbol {display: none;}
```

```html
s

    <div class="frac">
        <span>2</span>
        <span class="symbol">/</span>
        <span class="bottom">7</span>
        
    </div>
    &times;
    <div class="frac">
        <span>4</span>
        <span class="symbol">/</span>
        <span class="bottom">3</span>
        
    </div>

?
```

You can also achieve this with a little bit of pure JavaScript like:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("fractions");

/**Fraction one*/
elem.innerHTML = frac(2, 7);
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + ' &times; ';
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + frac(4, 3);


/**Fraction two*/

elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + "<BR /><BR />" + frac(10, 6);
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + ' &times; ';
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + frac(9, 5);

function frac(num1, num2)
{ 
  return '<div class="frac"><span>'+num1+'</span><span class="bottom">'+num2+'</span></div>';
}
```

```css
.frac {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    letter-spacing: 0.001em;
    text-align: center;
    
    }
.frac > span { 
    display: block; 
    padding: 0.1em; 
    }
.frac span.bottom {border-top: thin solid black;}
.symbol {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id ="fractions"></div>
```

Comment: i already used this same code but i want as it is (How i show in image, i mean i don't want "/" i want this "--" between numerator and denominator)

Comment: Great it works. But  @Luthando Loot every time using this long code is difficult to me while prepare the solution.Is there any another way to solve this problem?

Comment: i'm using simple web html page how can i implement this code in my page?

Comment: @lokesh wrap the javascript code with a script tag `<script> ....javascript code goes here...  </script>`, and then wrap the css with a style tag `<style> ...css...</style>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it exactly like this using css.

```
<p>S <span class="frac"><sup>2</sup><span>/</span><sub>7</sub></span>.</p>


 span.frac {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 50%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    span.frac > sup {
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
      font: inherit;
    }
    span.frac > span {
      display: none;
    }
    span.frac > sub {
      display: block;
      font: inherit;
    }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hx5oyotq/1/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some java script libraries like :

- [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)
- [GladTex](http://ans.hsh.no/home/mgg/gladtex/)
- ...

Answer (score 0):

For maximal compatibility, consider the following snippet in HTML 4.01 (without CSS, JavaScript, or any other modern gimmicks):

```html
<table rules="rows">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">s&nbsp;</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        &times;
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>            
      <td>7</td>
      <td>3</td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: output in Firefox]

Comment: @Community Image added. If you don't like it, see Fig. 1.