# How to write fractions in html?

Tags: html

How to write fractions in html?
I want to write some like this.."3 ½ years" in html.
 How to do it?

html:

```
  <html>
      <body>
          <p>3 1/2 years</p>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: See if this answer helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10081414/5586958

Comment: You can do it just like it's rendered in your question: "3 ½ years". View the page source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use;

```
&frac12;  3 ½
```

or you can use ASCII character code;

```
&#189;   3 ½
```

Hope helps;

Comment: `&frac12` without `;` is a parse error.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks, I forgot.

Comment: It works of course, but numeric character entity references in HTML are not ASCII. They are Unicode— as are all characters, regardless of the document encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```html
 3<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>years
```

Comment: You're welcome, if this answer your question do not forgot to mark it answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

`&frac12`

Then, your code should like this:

`<p>3 &frac12 years</p>`

3 ½ years

Comment: `&frac12` without `;` is a parse error.

Comment: @Oriol It's ok without `;` in Chrome. I have not test in other browsers, maybe with `;` is standard code style.

Comment: @ShuPeng HTML is able to recover from errors, but that does not mean you should write invalid code. Try it in XHTML and you will see the draconian error handling.

Answer (score 1):

```
¼   &frac14;
½   &frac12;
```

Just type nominator and denominator at the end