# html/css simple two-row / two-line element

Tags: html, css, rows, lines

Sorry, this is tricky for me to find through search

```
<div>
    <??> 
        <??> Question </??>   <??> X Y <??>
    </??>
    <button> Answer 1</button>
    <button> Answer 2</button>
    <button> Answer 3</button>
</div>
```

Where X and Y are numbers from 0 to 100; 
How to stack X on top of Y like a fraction, in good way? 
EDIT: It's example, markup can be added/changed.

Comment: `X<br>Y`…? Is the solution restricted to modifying the `??` parts? If so, why?

Comment: it is better to show the desired output in a image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write fraction value using html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525977/how-to-write-fraction-value-using-html)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<sup>X</sup>&frasl;<sub>Y</sub>
```

Output:

<sup>X</sup>⁄<sub>Y</sub>

Reference: http://changelog.ca/log/2008/07/01/writing_fractions_in_html

Answer (score 0):

You can place one number vertically over the other but you need to use CSS in tandem.

Declare in HTML:

```
<p>1 <span class="frac"><sup>X</sup><span>/</span><sub>Y</sub></span>.</p>
```

Then CSS:

```
span.frac {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
span.frac > sup {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  font: inherit;
}
span.frac > span {
  display: none;
}
span.frac > sub {
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
}
```

The span allows the text rendered in html for the client without CSS. Hope this can help you.